# JooScript & Prototype conflict - Object doesn't support property or method 'dispatchEvent'

Tags: prototypejs, conflict

I know jQuery and Prototype conflict can be solved using [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Is there an equivalent in either JooScript or Prototype?

Specifically I would like to use [Flotr](http://solutoire.com/flotr/) with [fxCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/).

Comment: Hmm, maybe I phrased the question badly - it's not jQuery/Prototype conflict that I'm concerned with - it's JooScript and Prototype. I was wondering whether JooScript or Prototype have equivalent of noConflict();

Comment: sorry, mixed up all the questions I was reading :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jooscript site:
http://burzak.com/proj/jooscript/

### snippet:-

Additionaly you can change Jooscript configuration:

```
joo_settings({
    compat_mode: true,
    runtime_typing: false
})
```

---

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It seems like you need to use jooscript_debug for it to work, but thanks for digging this up.

Comment: No problem. It could end up being useful for me some day. I am using prototype in my new job the past month.